# Changing operand's order get different result?

Tags: j

I don't get this simple example, this works :

```
    a.{~65 + i. 4 5
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
```

But when removing the reflex it doesn't :

```
   65{a. + i. 4 5
|domain error
|   65{a.    +i.4 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
 (65 + i.4 5) { a.
```

Evaluation in J is from right to left so your second expression starts with `a. + i. 4 5` which is a domain error.